# Crontab backup script not working properly

Tags: cron

i have a crontab job as root user, which backups some files from smb share. It's triggered as it should at 23:59 everyday, but it doesn't do it's thing. No files are being uploaded to backup storage. Strange thing because when i run the script manually it works perfectly fine...

Crontab entry looks like this:

```
59 23 * * * /mnt/backup/directory/smb_backup/smb.sh > /tmp/smb_backup 2>/tmp/smb_backup_error
```

Script smb.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
smbget -R -au smb://ip_address/sdb1/Dir/backup
```

Output from /tmp/smb_backup is empty...

/tmp/smb_backup shows

```
Downloaded 0b in 18 seconds
```

Logs are showing that cronjob is triggered with no issue

Anyone willing to help with solving the mystery? :)

Comment: iirc `smbget` has both a `-v` (verbose) and a `-d` (debug) option so you might be able to get some more diagnostic information that way. The latter takes a numeric level I think ex. `-d 3`

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673908/why-crontab-doesnt-execute-a-scheduled-bash-script/673918#673918

Comment: Mystery solved, in the script i had to specify a location of a backup folder. 

`#!/bin/sh

cd /tmp/backup

smbget -R -au smb://ip_address/sdb1/Dir/backup`

Thanks :)